# how to set query for show followed posts in home page

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to make query to show all followed posts in the main page, could you help me in doing this?

Here's my file **models.py**:

```
class Relation(models.Model):
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='follower')
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='following')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    avatar = models.FileField(default='default.jpg', verbose_name='avatar')
    age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    work_at = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkout this code:

```
followed_people = Relation.objects.filter(from_user=request.user).values('to_user')
            posts = Post.objects.filter(
                user__in=followed_people
            ) | Post.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```